# How do you toggle links to stay a certain color until clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a link, it makes it stay a certain thing, and then when clicked again, change back.

How do I go about doing this? Can i do it in html + css? or i need js?

Comment: Are you referring to image src, text colour, textual content? Please provide a bit more info in terms of what exactly you are after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS + jQuery:

CSS:

```
a{
    color: blue
}
a.clicked{
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

[You can check an example here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/L6VqK/)

Answer (score 0):

If only looking for pure Javascript and HTML:

```
function toggle_link(select){
    var color = select.style.color;
    select.style.color = (color == "blue" ? "green" : "blue");
}
```

And in your HTML, use the onclick attribute.

```
<a onclick="toggle_link(this)" style="color:blue">Click to change color!</a>
```

A working fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebYKs/)

Answer (score -3):

You'll definitely need JavaScript for that. (If you want to 'cheat' create 2 HTML pages with the same content except the links, so you can link them together but with a different name.)

Comment: Sorry, but having two pages is absolutely rediculous