# Indesign CS6, Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am a javascript beginner. I am working in indesign CS6. I have assigned paragraph and character styles to all the fonts being used throughout my document. Using character styles I have changed the color of some type to be purple. The purple text is being used to call specific attention to that text. However I want to be able to toggle on and off the purple text. When I toggle off the purple I want the text to change to gray. I do need to be able to change it back to purple as well. Is there anyway to do this using script?

Thank you!

Comment: What actions will toogle the text color? A click? After a certain period of time?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated swatch and change its color components to fit your taste.
All references e.g. from within styles will follow.

```
// assuming the swatch is already created
var swatch = app.activeDocument.swatches.itemByName("purple");
swatch.properties = {model:1886548851, space:1129142603, colorValue:[0, 0, 0, 30]};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script changes the internal color setting of the specified character style, from a 'purple'-named swatch to a 'grey'-names swatch, and vice-versa.

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;   
var charStyle = myDoc.characterStyles.item('My Character Style');
var purple = myDoc.colors.item('purple');
var grey = myDoc.colors.item('grey');
if (charStyle.fillColor == purple)
    charStyle.fillColor = grey;
else charStyle.fillColor = purple;
```

If it's set to Purple then it changes to Grey, and if it's set to Grey it changes to Purple.

(change the swatch names and character style to suit your needs)

Answer (score -3):

you can try this :

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/toggle-change-row-color

try to create a class for your "purple text" , and add/remove the class to change the colors.

there is a similar question at this link :

[How do you toggle links to stay a certain color until clicked again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712672/how-do-you-toggle-links-to-stay-a-certain-color-until-clicked-again)

Comment: He is not asking about jQuery, he is asking about Javascript. Also, if you cant take your time to write a proper answer and will only post links to other resources, don't even try to help.